# C++ const member functions

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I have a syntax error that is puzzling

Previous code:

```
class A {
public:
    void process(const string& str) {};
};
```

I have

```
A a;
a.process("abcd");
```

all is well 
now I change the process member function to a const

```
void process(const string& str) const {};
```

and now 
`a.process("abcd");` get a compile error about str being a const char[5]...

How the const addition impact the syntax error. I thought const only (in this context) meant that the member variables will not change?

Thoughts on this?

Comment: Please post compilable that demonstrates the problem. As-is, it's difficult to even guess at what you're seeing, not to mention what's causing it.

Comment: You are doing something different than what you are telling here, there is no problem with const function: http://ideone.com/0RXZl

Comment: You state that you see "a compile error".... Please tell us *exactly* what the compiler error is, and what line it refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `const` to the end of the method declaration would not have changed the semantics of the `str` parameter.  Either something else is happening, or the compiler has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine. Consequently, you have also made some other modifications that affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a const qualifier to your member function means that object on which your calling your function can be const:

```
const A a;
a.process("abcd");
```

It doesn't have anything to do with your array of const chars.